# ¿Por qué no puedo guardar las cookies en un .txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
submit_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/footer/div/button[2]')[0]
submit_button.click()
cookie = driver.get_cookies()
archivocookie = open('cookie.txt', 'wb')
archivocookie.write(cookie)
archivocookie.close()
```

El error es el siguiente, no sé como solucionarlo, ¿alguna ayuda? por favor

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'

Comment: `cookie` es una lista. Prueba a imprimirla a ver qué contiene. Posiblemente sean cadenas. Si es así tienes que abrir en fichero en modo texto (sin la b), e iterar por la lista de cadenas para volcar cada una por separado, con un "\n" al final.

Comment: Efectivamente tal como dice @abulafia, no puedes guardar una lista tal cual. Además, el modo `b` se usa para binarios (por ejemplo, imágenes). Lo correcto sería que abrieses en modo `w`. En vez de iterar la lista, podrías hacer algo como esto: `write('\n'.join(cookie))`

Comment: Gracias, pudo ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

El código correcto es:

```
archivocookie = open('cookie.txt', 'w')

archivocookie.write(str(cookie))
```

Comment: Podrías explicar brevemente por qué resolvió tu problema, así la respuesta le servirá a más personas y márcala como respuesta para tu pregunta.